# How can I implement a proper data access layer if I dont want to use Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

I hate EF its given me nothing but problems and my models are really not that complex. But the only tutorials I can find are about EF! Help!

Comment: I've provided an answer with a short list of recommended subjects to look into when considering rolling your own data access layer.  They should give you a good base to start with, from which you can ask more detailed questions as they arise.

Comment: I see thank you so much. In your opinion, which is the easiest? I have a simple project for school and it only has about 4-5 tables

Comment: If you are going for something quick and dirty for a throw-away project, I would just use something like Dapper or Massive with convention based mapping (class names matching DB field names).  If you want to go a bit deeper for experience, I'd still use Dapper for the actual data access, but wrap the calls in domain specific repositories.  The repositories tend to be pretty simple to start - only really getting complicated with either more sophisticated queries/optimization concerns or the need for transaction support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend looking into:

1. Repository Pattern: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx
2. Mapper Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern
3. ADO.NET: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
4. Micro ORMs (http://www.diplo.co.uk/blog/2011/8/15/small-is-beautiful-net-micro-orms.aspx) such as Dapper (https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) and Massive (https://github.com/FransBouma/Massive).

Edited to add:

5. Unit of Work Pattern: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx and http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application